# jQuery Circle Menu. Change options after init

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using this jQuery plugin in one of my projects:

[jQUery Circle Menu](http://zikes.github.io/circle-menu/)
The plugin is really easy to use, but following the documentation I don't see any ways of changing the properties after init. For example:

```
 $('ul').circleMenu({
      item_diameter: 40,
      circle_radius: 100,
      direction: 'bottom-right'
    });
```

If I want to change let's say the direction property. How could I do that:

```
$('ul').circleMenu("options", "direction", val)
```

That does not work.

Comment: what does changing the direction accomplish?

Comment: The direction of the items in relation to the center. top will place the items above the center, in a 90 degree semicircle centered upwards. top-half will create a full 180 degree semicircle. full will create a full 360 degree circle, with the first item appearing at the top.

Comment: It would appear that circle-menu does not provide for changing the options after initialisation. There's an "init" command, which will re-initialise but with the same options as were originally applied. If there was a "destroy" command, then you could destroy and re-initialise with different options, however the documentation gives no indication that "destroy" exists. You could try re-initialising without destroying but the end result may behave erratically.

Comment: I had to implement my own destroy.

Answer (score 0):

change the option, then re-initialize:

```
$('ul').circleMenu({direction:'bottom-right'}).circleMenu('init');
```

Answer (score 0):

In the absence of an "options" command or a "destroy" command, the safe way to change options is somewhat convoluted.

First, initialise as follows :

- assign the default options map in a convenient outer scope
- make a clean copy of the original unstyled element(s)
- style the original element(s) with `.circleMenu(options)`

```js
var circleMenuOptions = {
    item_diameter: 40,
    circle_radius: 100,
    direction: 'bottom-right'
};
var $cleanCopy = $('ul').clone(true,true);
$('ul').circleMenu(circleMenuOptions);
```

And later, re-initialise as follows :

- replace the styled element(s) with a copy of the clean copy
- initialise the new, clean elements with `.circleMenu(modified_copy_of_the_default_options)`.

```js
$('ul')
    .replaceWith($cleanCopy.clone(true,true))
    .circleMenu($.extend({}, circleMenuOptions, {
        "direction": val
    }));
```

After re-initialisation, the default options and the clean copy of the unstyled element(s) will remain available to be used again for another re-initialisation.